# How to create a scroll-based parallax animation that continues to ease after scroll

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, parallax

This is more of a "how do they do this" question than a need for a specific solution.

I've visited a few sites that have an elegant and natural-appearing easing on page elements which react to page scrolling (to initiate) but also continue after the scrolling stops (allowing the elements to ease into a stopping point).

Having looked up various searches for combinations of "parallax," "scrolling," "easing," etc., I can't find a starting point for how to achieve a similar experience.

#### Examples of this interactivity

**https://la.pizzeriamozza.com/**

- Seen in the **photo** in the first "Pizzeria Mozza is known for its California ingredients..." section as well as the **cards** for "Bar Special" and "Red Sauce Dinner" further down the page (as of 10/3/2020).

**https://droitthemes.com/wp/oppi-one-page/**

- Seen in the hero banner's **device image** and the **screenshot/UI images** in the "It's the food you love, delivered" section (along with other elements on the page)

In both sites, it appears that the elements have a dynamically changing `transform: translate3d`
style that is directly reactive to page scrolling. But, how that gets implemented & applied... I don't know.

I've tried looking up similar components used in each site (via BuiltWith.com), but that didn't reveal anything helpful (to me).

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a couple plugins that I have used - https://dixonandmoe.com/rellax/ and https://min30327.github.io/luxy.js/

Comment: Thank you @dantheman ! Also, just knowing the terms **"inertia scroll"** and **"momentum scroll"** have completely opened up my world of research. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img1 {
display: block;
width: 100%;
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1640777/pexels-photo-1640777.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
.img2 {
display: block;
width: 100%;
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1410236/pexels-photo-1410236.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
.img3 {
display: block;
width: 100%;
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2641886/pexels-photo-2641886.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
.color1 {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background: red;
}
.color2 {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="img1"></div>
<div class="color1"></div>
<div class="img2"></div>
<div class="color2"></div>
<div class="img3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution & code, @Ishita Ray. The parallax stuff here looks & works great. The original request was for a component that would add easing. I found solutions that I'm exploring in Luxy.js, Rellax, and Locomotive-scroll. Thanks again, though, for the kind help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment from @dantheman - my question is resolved. Some key takeaways for anyone who may be searching out a similar solution are the terms "**inertia scroll**" and "**momentum scroll**" (the terms for the type of interactivity/behavior that I was seeking).

Along with dantheman's suggestions of:

[dixonandmoe.com/rellax](https://dixonandmoe.com/rellax/)
and
[min30327.github.io/luxy.js](https://min30327.github.io/luxy.js/)

I've found that [locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll](https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/) appears to be just what I need.

It's worth also adding that Rellax doesn't have the easing I was seeking, but adding a CSS transform transition as [noted here](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax/issues/73#issuecomment-328111594) can get you something pretty close.